# Determine if two iso images are equal

Tags: dd, diff, iso, disk-image

I've recently made multiple images of several SD cards on multiple machines using `dd`.  I haven't done a stellar job with my naming, and have some duplicates. How can I quickly determine if two images are equal?  I've been using `diff` but it takes a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`md5sum *.img | sort`

Should make any duplicates obvious.

Comment: Even ... | uniq -c and grep out the singles

Comment: Or you could loop mount and just compare the files. Or you could just compare the first 500bytes of the images which if the SDcards are FAT32 formatted would included their allocations (free/used space).

Comment: Would `md5sum` be any faster than `diff`?  If `diff` returns `Binary files 1.bin and 2.bin differ` if two files are different and nothing if they are the same, I would have thought that it would have outputted different status right when it found the first difference.  Not so for `md5sum`.

Comment: not faster but it can confim both files are equal  & md5sum is the good one compared to the site/machine  they have been downloaded from at first :)

Comment: @francoisP  Would `diff` then not detect a difference?  I don't understand what you mean by `md5sum is the good one compared to the site/machine they have been downloaded from at first`.  Please elaborate.

Comment: diff makes diff between files that's all                                                                    md5sum local generates a hash     that hash will be same wherever a copy of the file is worldwide   so  all copies of the file have same ... so it is better than diff on that point (only)    because then you know your local files are similare between themselves but also to the original  so they are note corrupted  or copied from a corrupted copy of the orginial